# Trying to understand Bitmap.Config.ARBG_8888

Tags: android, colors, bit-manipulation, pixel

I'm trying to understand packing of color bytes for ARGB_8888 format.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#ARGB_8888) states that packing should be done using this formula:

```
int color = (A & 0xff) << 24 | (B & 0xff) << 16 | (G & 0xff) << 8 | (R & 0xff);
```

But shouldn't it be instead:

```
int color = (A & 0xff) << 24 | (R & 0xff) << 16 | (G & 0xff) << 8 | (B & 0xff);
```

When I unpack a sample pixel from a ARGB_8888 color encoded bitmap that has all red pixels, I'm using:

```
    final int r = (p >> 16) & 0xff;
    final int g = (p >> 8) & 0xff;
    final int b = p & 0xff;
```

Which indeed returns me correct values for every color.

My point is, is it the documentation wrong or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct and the documentation is wrong. If you look at the [Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Color.java) for Color.java it's done the second way:

```
* <h4>Encoding</h4>
* <p>The four components of a color int are encoded in the following way:</p>
* <pre class="prettyprint">
* int color = (A & 0xff) << 24 | (R & 0xff) << 16 | (G & 0xff) << 8 | (B & 0xff);
* </pre>
```

and further down...

```
@ColorInt
public static int argb(
        @IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) int alpha,
        @IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) int red,
        @IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) int green,
        @IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) int blue) {
    return (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
}
```

Comment: Seriously. I copied this code for use in JNI before, and the colors were off. Then I was like, wait a second, I switched it all to ARGB (in order), and boom perfect. Their documentation is still misleading today >.>