# Packing Java bitmap into ByteBuffer - byte order doesn't match pixel format and endianness (ARM)

Tags: android, bitmap, arm, endianness, bytebuffer

I'm a bit puzzled with internal representation of Bitmap's pixels in ByteBuffer (testing on ARM/little endian):

1) In the Java layer I create an ARGB bitmap and fill it with 0xff112233 color:

```
Bitmap sampleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(sampleBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0x11,0x22, 0x33));
canvas.drawRect(0,0, sampleBitmap.getWidth(), sampleBitmap.getHeight(), paint);
```

To test, sampleBitmap.getPixel(0,0) indeed returns 0xff112233 that matches ARGB pixel format.

2) The bitmap is packed into direct ByteBuffer before passing to the native layer:

```
 final int byteSize = sampleBitmap.getAllocationByteCount();
 ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(byteSize);
 //byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);// See below
 sampleBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
```

To test, regardless of the buffer's order setting, in the debugger I see the byte layout which doesn't quite match ARGB but more like a big endian RGBA (or little endian ABGR!?)

```
  byteBuffer.rewind();
  final byte [] out = new byte[4];
  byteBuffer.get(out, 0, out.length);
```

> ```
> out = {byte[4]@12852} 
>  0 = (0x11)
>  1 = (0x22)
>  2 = (0x33)
>  3 = (0xFF)
> ```

Now, I'm passing this bitmap to the native layer where I must extract pixels and I would expect Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 to be represented, depending on buffer's byte order as:

a) byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN):

> ```
> out = {byte[4]@12852} 
>  0 = (0x33)
>  1 = (0x22)
>  2 = (0x11)
>  3 = (0xFF)
> ```

or

b) byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN):

> ```
> out = {byte[4]@12852} 
>  0 = (0xFF)
>  1 = (0x11)
>  2 = (0x22)
>  3 = (0x33)
> ```

I can make the code which extracts the pixels work based on above output but I don't like it since I can't explain the behaviour which I hope someone will do :)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The little-endian layout looks entirely correct to me. What were you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting either a) or b). What I've got doesn't look like any ARGB layout but some variation of RGBA.

Comment: Ok. The documentation for `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` says _"Use this formula to pack into 32 bits:

 `int color = (A & 0xff) << 24 | (B & 0xff) << 16 | (G & 0xff) << 8 | (R & 0xff);`"_

Comment: Yah, that's apparently an issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56832572/trying-to-understand-bitmap-config-arbg-8888

Comment: Also, that can be validated by bitmap.getPixel() which returns 0xff112233 (ARGB) as expected.

Comment: @Michael Based on my comments, do you think something is missing here or I completely misunderstood it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the implementation. Both `getPixel` and `copyPixelsToBuffer` just call their native counterparts. 
[Bitmap_getPixels](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/jni/android/graphics/Bitmap.cpp#938) specifies an output format:

```
SkImageInfo dstInfo = SkImageInfo::Make(1, 1, kBGRA_8888_SkColorType, kUnpremul_SkAlphaType, sRGB);
bitmap.readPixels(dstInfo, &dst, dstInfo.minRowBytes(), x, y);
```

It effectively asks the bitmap to give the pixel value converted to `BGRA_8888` (which becomes `ARGB` because of different native and java endianness).

[Bitmap_copyPixelsToBuffer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/jni/android/graphics/Bitmap.cpp#1005) in its turn just copies raw data:

```
memcpy(abp.pointer(), src, bitmap.computeByteSize());
```

And does not have any conversion. It basically returns the data in the same format it uses to store it. Let's find out what this inner format is.

[Bitmap_creator](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/jni/android/graphics/Bitmap.cpp#334) is used to create a new bitmap and it gets the format from the config passed by calling

```
SkColorType colorType = GraphicsJNI::legacyBitmapConfigToColorType(configHandle);
```

Looking at the [legacyBitmapConfigToColorType](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android/graphics/Graphics.cpp#326) implementation, `ARGB_8888` (which has index 5) becomes `kN32_SkColorType`.

`kN32_SkColorType` is from [skia](https://skia.googlesource.com/skia) library, so looking at [the definitions](https://skia.googlesource.com/skia/+/refs/heads/android/pie/include/core/SkImageInfo.h#67) find the comment

```
kN32_SkColorType is an alias for whichever 32bit ARGB format is the 
"native" form for skia's blitters. Use this if you don't have a swizzle 
preference for 32bit pixels.
```

and below is the definition:

```
#if SK_PMCOLOR_BYTE_ORDER(B,G,R,A)
    kN32_SkColorType = kBGRA_8888_SkColorType,
#elif SK_PMCOLOR_BYTE_ORDER(R,G,B,A)
    kN32_SkColorType = kRGBA_8888_SkColorType,
```

`SK_PMCOLOR_BYTE_ORDER` is defined [here](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/master/include/core/SkPostConfig.h#L168) and it says `SK_PMCOLOR_BYTE_ORDER(R,G,B,A) will be true on a little endian machine`, which is our case. So it means the bitmap is stored in `kRGBA_8888_SkColorType` format internally.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough investigation. It explains the behaviour but it would be good that it is mentioned somewhere in the docs that the internal byte order when working with bitmap buffer could be different.

Comment: I totally agree, the documentation is not full here. It says `The content of the bitmap is copied into the buffer as-is.`, but does not say what it actually is.